# How to control which fields from POST data in ModelForm overwrite fields from instance that is passed in?

Tags: python, django

This is my setup:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('param1','param2')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    param1 = models.CharField()
    param2 = models.CharField()

form = MyForm(request.POST, instance=my_model_instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_model_instance = form.save()
```

Suppose `my_model_instance.param1 == 'foo'` and `my_model_instance.param2 == 'bar'`. Now if user enters 'spam' or leaves the field blank in my form and submits it, how would I control that 'spam' or '' does not overwrite params from `my_model_instance`?
So I dont get `new_model_instance.param1 == 'spam'` or `new_model_instance.param2 == ''` but instead I get values preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `param1` and `param2` depend on each other then you need to write a `.clean()` function on your form:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('param1','param2')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
        param1 = cleaned_data.get("param1")
        param1 = cleaned_data.get("param2")

        if param1 and param2:
            # Only do something if both fields are valid so far.
            if param1 != param2:
                raise forms.ValidationError("param1 does not equal param2")

        return cleaned_data
```

If `param1` and `param2` ~do not~ depend on each other then you need to write a `.clean_<fieldname>()` function on your form:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('param1','param2')

    def clean_param1(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['param1']

        if data == 'spam':
            raise forms.ValidationError("param1 is spam")

        return data
```

Comment: I don't want to raise ValidationError.
I want something like this:
`if data == 'spam': data = my_model_instance.param1`
but I don't know how can I access param1 from this instance I passed into the form?

Comment: Instead of raising the ValidationError you have access to `self.instance` which is the model.

Answer (score 0):

This form will dynamically exclude any fields submitted with empty values, so they won't overwrite anything on the existing model instance:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if data is not None:
            for key, value in data.items():
                if value.strip() == '':
                    exclude = set(self._meta.exclude or [])
                    exclude.add(key)
                    self._meta.exclude = tuple(exclude)
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(data=data, *args, **kwargs)
```